# java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn issue

Tags: java, clojure

I'm coding a basic exponential function for an assignment, and i can't figure out why i'm getting this error. This is my code:

```
(def epsilon 0.000001)

(def exponentialing
  (fn [F S T x]
    (if
      (<= T epsilon)
      S
      (recur (+ F 1) (+ S T) (* T(/ x F)) x))))


(def exp
  (fn [x]
    (exponentialing 1.0 0.0 1.0 x)))
```

I'm getting the error message on the last line, I'm assuming it has to do with the doubles or the x in the argument spot

Comment: I simply copy/pasted your code and everything works as-is. Both `(exp 5)` and `(exp (java.lang.Double. 5.0))` return the appropriate 148.41315852164777, even with the `... (* T(/ ...)` bit. Tested on both Clojure 1.8.0 and 1.9.0-alpha12.

Comment: show us how `exp` is called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were missing a space char in the `recur` line.  I also simplified your functions from `def` to `defn`.  Also, you failed to call `exp` in your original version:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def epsilon 0.000001)

(defn exponentialing
  [F S T x]
  (if
    (<= T epsilon)
    S
    (recur (+ F 1) (+ S T) (* T (/ x F)) x)))

(defn exp 
  [x]
  (exponentialing 1.0 0.0 1.0 x))

(spyx (exp 3))

 > lein run
(exp 3) => 20.085536488379084
```

Comment: the space between `T` and `(` has nothing to do with it. I pasted his code exactly and it works fine.

Comment: Funny.... When I pasted his code I got the same error he did.  Added the space and it went away.  I haven't tried to diagnose beyond that.